# Bash script find Maximum MTU

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

PKT_SIZE='ifconfig | grep "MULTICAST" | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1'
HOSTNAME=$1

count=`ping -M do -c 1 -s $PKT_SIZE $HOSTNAME | grep -c "Frag needed"`

while [ $count -eq 1 ]; do
 ((PKT_SIZE--))
 count=$((`ping -M do -c 1 -s $PKT_SIZE $HOSTNAME | grep -c "Frag needed"`))
done

printf "Your Maximum MTU is [ $((PKT_SIZE + 28)) ] \n"
```

Why ((PKT_SIZE--)) decrement not work?

$1 - this is i write website for ping

Comment: `PKT_SIZE='ifconfig | grep "MULTICAST" | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1'`, the command substitution won't work. It should be `PKT_SIZE=\`ifconfig | grep "MULTICAST" | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1\``

Comment: yes, i know i just inserted from the editor

Comment: Sometimes it's better both for understanding, and debugging ! to do complex expressions in several steps; that way, the intermediates can be checked and maybe validated in the script.

Answer (score 0):

You require a space before and after your expression in (( )).

Hence (( PKT_SIZE-- ))

Comment: It works. `a=3; ((a--)); echo $a` print `2`. The space is optional.

Comment: But from a style viewpoint, I would use the pre-dec operation in this case - why use post-dec if you do not require the previous value ?

Comment: The position of `--` is irrelevant. Because it hasn't used the value of `PKT_SIZE` in the expression.

Comment: Hence, go for the most straightforward operator !

Comment: (Post-dec says "decrement variable BUT give me the previous value !")